# Accessing Azure SQL Database with on-premises web application(s)

Tags: azure-sql-database

Can I connect my locally hosted web applications to Azure SQL Database?

Moreover, can I host only the SQL database service in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can connect to Azure SQL Database from your localhost.

When you create the Azure SQL server instance you will get an address like yourazuresqlserver.database.windows.net and it will be on the standard MS SQL port 1433. Use this as your servername and port just like you would for on premise sql servers.

Only difference is you have to white list your clients that will connect to the server, it is under the "allowed ip addresses" section of the configure tab.

Comment: Forgive me if this might be off-topic but can I also connect the SQL Management Studio to the Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Yes it will work as well, not sure if you need a specific version of SQL Management Studio but I'm using 2014 to connect to Azure SQL. Just remember to white list the IP address you are connecting from.

Comment: Thank you for clearing it up for me. I wanted to up-vote your answer but my reputation is not yet high enough.